# Multiple Pattern matching in Hibernate Annotation

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, pattern-matching, hibernate-annotations

I need to validate one field for the below case. for this i need to write a regular expression via annotations...

1. If value is other than (only 9 numeric digits) or (2 numeric digits followed by a hyphen followed by 7 numeric digits)-(show error message 1)
2. It can't be all the nine digits are zeros.-(show error message 2)

Comment: whats your HTML so we can incorporate it with this?

Comment: I don't understand 3. - a digit can never be a space, so if condition 1 is met, condition 3 is irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim:yes you are correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do:

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\d{2}-?\d{7}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?=.*([1-9])) # Assert that there is at least one digit > 0, capture that digit
\d{2}         # Match any two digits
-?            # Match an optional hyphen
\d{7}         # Match any seven digits
$             # End of string
```

In order to check if condition 1 or 2 was met, check group number 1 (`$1`) after the match - if it's undefined, then there was no nonzero digit in the string.

Comment: It is working... Could you pls do it for step1 and step2 seperately? I tried to do first step alone...but something wrong for me...

Comment: @Saravanan: Just remove the `(?=...)` part, then only condition 1 is checked. If that succeeds, you can simply check whether `[1-9]` is found in the matched string.

Comment: I checked my first condition through ^\\d{2}-?\\d{7}$. Now i want to check, atleast one digit should be in [1-9] in the nine digit input...

Comment: Yes, so just check if `[1-9]` finds a match.

Comment: You're probably using `Pattern.matcher()` then which forces the regex to match the entire string. You want to use `Matcher.find()` which allows submatches and returns a boolean value.